# TypeError: object is not a function in node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I'm a beginner to nodejs and i'm developing a **REST** api to interact with mongodb. I used express and mongoose as explained in following tutorial :

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/08/restful-api-node-mongodb/

I have setup mongo db and here is my server code in node js :

```
var express     =   require("express");
var app         =   express();
var bodyParser  =   require("body-parser");
var router      =   express.Router();
var mongoOp     =   require("./models/mongo");
//var user        =   require("./Entities/User");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended" : false}));
router.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.json({"error" : false,"message" : "Hello World"});
});
router.route("/users")
    .get(function(req,res){
        var response = {};
        mongoOp.find({},function(err,data){
        // Mongo command to fetch all data from collection.
            if(err) {
                response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error fetching data"};
            } else {
                response = {"error" : false,"message" : data};
            }
            res.json(response);
        });
    })
    .post(function(req,res){
        var db = new mongoOp();
        var response = {};
        // fetch email and password from REST request.
        // Add strict validation when you use this in Production.
        db.userEmail = req.body.email;
        // Hash the password using SHA1 algorithm.
        db.userPassword =  require('crypto')
                          .createHash('sha1')
                          .update(req.body.password)
                          .digest('base64');
        db.save(function(err){
        // save() will run insert() command of MongoDB.
        // it will add new data in collection.
            if(err) {
                response = {"error" : true,"message" : "Error adding data"};
            } else {
                response = {"error" : false,"message" : "Data added"};
            }
            res.json(response);
        });
    });
app.use('/',router);
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to PORT 3000");
```

and here is my mongo module

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Appdb");
//Create instance of Schema
var mongoSchema = mongoose.schema;
//Create Schema
var userSchema = {
    "userEmail":String,
    "userPassword":String
}
//Create model if not exists.
module.export = mongoose.model('userLogin',userSchema);
```

When i used RESTClient (an addon in firefox to test REStful application) it gives following error :

> TypeError: object is not a function    at E:\node\server.js:30:18
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) .........

[image]

Can anyone help me please...

Answer (score 1):

module.exports = mongoose.model('userLogin',userSchema);

use exports not export

Comment: Now it give me

TypeError: Not a string or buffer
   at TypeError (native)
   at Hash.update (crypto.js:119:16)
   at E:\node\server.js:38:28

error...

Comment: db.userPassword =  require('crypto')
                          .createHash('sha1')
                          .update(req.body.password)
                          .digest('base64');
something wrong with this. can u check your req.body.password is atleast some string using console.log

Comment: @Piysuh i display as undifined , is that mean when i pass password via RestClient is not passed to the api?

Comment: req.body is not coming out to be what you are passing through rest client
I see you are using body parser which is correct .

Comment: also make sure in your rest client in your request headers data is being sent 
as application/json 
This is the only issue